# is there any openerp documentation about important tables of the framework

Tags: odoo

Is there any documentation available describing the important tables of the openobject framework (not the addons) and flow of control inside the framework from file to file preferably for 6.1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their is no such document which highlights important tables of the OpenEPR but if you want to check I will suggest to see the following files :

File `server/openerp/addons/base/base.sql` is Most Important file which prepare the BASE for the OpenERP.

For OpenERP Service Check following files

- server/openerp/service/http_server.py
- server/openerp/service/netrpc_server.py
- server/openerp/service/security.py
- server/openerp/service/web_services.py [Hosted Fice Web Service are
  here]
- server/openerp/service/websrv_lib.py

Core Open Object Framework Called ORM is under :

- server/openerp/osv/expression.py
- server/openerp/osv/fields.py
- server/openerp/osv/orm.py
- server/openerp/osv/osv.py
- server/openerp/osv/query.py

New **WSGI** Service are manage here :
 - server/openerp/wsgi/core.py
 - server/openerp/wsgi/proxied.py

Database, Modules and Registry and Load Manager :

- server/openerp/modules/db.py
- server/openerp/modules/graph.py
- server/openerp/modules/loading.py
- server/openerp/modules/migration.py
- server/openerp/modules/module.py
- server/openerp/modules/registry.py

All Internal Resource , this table are used for intenal usage of the ERP like view , action, server action :

- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_attachment.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_config_parameter.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_cron.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_default.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_exports.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_filters.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_mail_server.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model_constraint.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model_relation.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_needaction.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_rule.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_sequence.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_translation.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_menu.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py
- server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_values.py

Workflow Services are under this files :

- server/openerp/workflow/common.py
- server/openerp/workflow/instance.py
- server/openerp/workflow/wkf_expr.py
- server/openerp/workflow/wkf_service.py
- server/openerp/workflow/workitem.py

Well this are hell lot of files to check but i guess after this you do not need any other help, you will understand all OpenERP.

Thanks

Comment: and this are on current OpenERP Trunk Version. but 6.1 is similer in term or their file and resource path, so you can check both same place

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I have found is the [developer book](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/index.html), particularly the [architecture chapter](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/02_architecture.html) and the [list of ORM methods](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#orm-methods), although it doesn't give much internal detail. Most of that documentation tells you how to build a module on top of the framework without explaining how the framework actually runs.

I have learned most of what I know about the internal workings by [tracing through the code in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9086069/4794). Either pause the application before making a request, set a breakpoint early in the [dispatch chain](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/6.1/view/head:/openerp/service/web_services.py#L575), or put a breakpoint in a specific model method that you want to follow. The workflow code was particularly difficult for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Moreover, at the moment of answering, the official documentation is a mixture of partial documentation for versions 6.1, 7 and 8.